# Hide a number in excel 2007 spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using excel for a mileage log.  I want to be able to hide the "Daily Accumulated Odometer" number if there were no kilometers put on that day but still need that number to add to the next time i have kilometers. When i use the IF function and there isnt any kilometage for that day i can make it go blank, but that just makes that cell a zero and if the next day i have some kilometage then it has nothing to add to. So i was wondering if there is some formula that hides a value in a cell but retains the value so the next time there is data to add it will calculate and display.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting.  Set the format to change the text to white if the the condition is true; usually an IF statement is used for the condition.